# Where priority and return

Tags: mysql

I have a table  that one column is index that can have zero or some row with values  (without use min())

```
users table
╔════════╗
║ index  ║
╠════════╣
║  1     ║
║  2     ║
║  3     ║
╚════════╝
```

i want just one row with min value

```
select * from users where  if exist index 1 then return if 2 return ...
```

Comment: select min(index) from users?

Comment: this code is subquery ,i just use in 'where'

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Select * from users order by index limit 0,1
```